# Android: Cannot cast from View to Gallery

Tags: android, view, gallery, android-gallery

I'd like to make a Gallery in android. In order to set the adapter in need to get the gallery which I defined in my xml file. Im doing that as:
Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
But with this code I can't compile my project, since I get the Error "Cannot cast from View to Gallery". My xml-file looks like this:
"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
 <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="bottom"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Anybody knows how to solve my problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Your code looks fine.
Check if you have the correct import for  `Gallery`

```
import android.widget.Gallery;
```

Comment: aahhh..ok. I figured my error. I named my class Gallery as well, and so I had a name-conflict. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you just created the Object instance for Gallery. Gallery is a AdapterView. So you must set Adapter for the Content. please check this [sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)